# Email from mailing list from self

Tags: gmail

I'm subscribed to a few [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/) mailing lists. When someone sends an email to the list, I of course get an email from the list. My question is with regards to what happens if I send an email to the list. Naturally, I would expect that since I'm subscribed to the list, I, too, would receive an email from the list when it is me that posted/emailed the list. However, I am not seeing that email come in, even when others tell me I've successfully broadcast the email.

Is this expected behavior in Gmail?

Or perhaps Mailman is configured to not broadcast the email to the sender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is expected behavior from Gmail. From the docs:

> When you send mail to any group or mailing list you subscribe to, Gmail automatically skips your inbox and archives the message to save you time and prevent clutter. The message will appear in your inbox if someone responds to it or if there is an error delivering the message. If you'd like to view your message, you can find it in Sent Mail or All Mail.

[Link to Gmail help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6588?hl=en)

Also, there is a setting in Mailman called ""Receive your own posts to the list?" which lets you control, well, whether to receive your own posts to the list. So it depends on how the list has been configured.

[Link to Mailman docs](http://www.list.org/mailman-member/node23.html)

Comment: So these lists (Mailman, MailChimp, etc.) know not to broadcast email to the sender? Or does GMail automatically delete the email when it comes back?

Comment: Updated my answer now, the answer could actually be "both".